# L'espressione "alcuna differenza" in una frase interrogativa

Tags: grammar, adjectives, sentences

Ho letto queste due frasi che contengono l'espressione "alcuna differenza" o "qualche differenza", la prima è una negazione, mentre la seconda è una frase interrogativa:

> Matematicamente non c'è *alcuna differenza* tra particelle e
>   antiparticelle, a parte il segno della carica.

> C'è *qualche differenza* tra le due teorie?

La mia domanda è: sarebbe corretto usare "alcuna differenza" nella frase interrogativa? Cioè,

> C'è *alcuna differenza* tra le due teorie?

è una costruzione corretta?

Comment: Può anche essere corretta, ma la trovo affettata e inusuale. Nota che anche l'uso di "alcuno" in frasi negative è declinante: *non c'è nessuna differenza* è forse addirittura più comune di *non c'è alcuna differenza*.

Comment: L'uso dell'aggettivo e pronome indefinito _"alcuno"_ è questione di registro linguistico. Chi lo usa in una frase interrogativa difficilmente lo farà in combinazione con "_c'è_" che appartiene ad un registro più basso. Probabilmente dirà «V'è forse alcuna differenza tra…», in associazione con "v'è" e aggiungendo un pizzico di retorica ("forse"). Potrebbe persino spingersi a dire «V'è forse differenza alcuna tra…» - questo però è registro colto da accademici, studiosi, artisti, etc. Altrimenti dirà «C'è qualche differenza tra…» o «Esiste qualche differenza tra…» o «Esistono differenze tra…».

Comment: Capisco. Grazie mille! I vostri commenti sono davvero utili!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non si può dire che si tratti di una costruzione non corretta dato che l'aggettivo "alcuno" o "alcuna" al singolare col significato di "qualche" è stato usato nella lingua italiana anche in frasi interrogative, come in questo esempio proveniente di un poema Seicentesco di Giovanni Battista Marino che ho tratto del [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI01/GDLI_01_ocr_306.pdf):

> Udrò di te mai più richiamo alcuno, 
>   ministro di follie, fabro d’errori?

Tuttavia, questo uso di "alcuno" è da considerarsi arcaico. Vittorio Coletti, nel suo libro *Grammatica dell'italiano adulto*, spiega che, nell'italiano di oggi, "alcuno" e "alcuna" al singolare si usano soltanto in frasi negative, nelle quali, come menzionato da @egreg nel suo commento, sono anche in declino:

> Nel nostro caso è soprattutto il forbito *alcuni* a fare le spese, che resiste meglio solo se è in correlazione con *altri* («alcuni sono venuti, altri no»); a suo svantaggio gioca anche il fatto che è parola che al singolare ha valore negativo e può trovarsi solo in frase negativa («non c'è alcuna traccia di effrazione») e al plurale ne ha uno positivo; e quindi è troppo complicata. Nel *LIP*, il *Lessico di frequenza dell'italiano parlato*, *alcuno* è usato quasi solo al plurale. 
>         Nell'italiano antico *alcuno* poteva essere usato anche al singolare in frasi positive, ma oggi non è più ammesso, e la nostra lingua tende a comportarsi come il francese (dove *aucun* si trova solo in frasi negative) e a differire dallo spagnolo e dal portoghese che conservano il valore positivo di *algún*. 
>         *Alcuno* al singolare patisce la concorrenza di *nessuno* (come in spagnolo) e stenta quindi, diversamente che in francese, anche in questo ruolo («non c'è nessuna traccia» è molto più attestato su Google di «non c'è alcuna traccia»).

Answer (score 4):

Sì, puoi perfettamente dirlo. Nel tuo esempio, alcuna e qualche significano un numero indeterminato di cose (astratte).

Principali significati di `alcuno/a`:

1. Un numero **indeterminato**, limitato e circoscritto, di persone o cose:

   Ho visto alcuni amici (Non specifichi esattamente quanti)
2. **Qualche**:

   Per alcun tempo (~ per qualche tempo)
3. **Nessuna**:

   Non hai voglia alcuna (~ Non hai nessuna voglia)

I principali significati di `qualche`:

1. **Alcuni, pochi**:

   Resta solo qualche giorno di tempo (Restano solo pochi giorni)
2. Numero **inderterminato** di una cosa astratta (~ alcuno/a):

   Ho accettato dopo qualche esitazione (Ho accettato con alcuna esitazione)

---

In generale, molto spesso questi aggettivi/pronomi possono scambiarsi, solo col tempo capirai quando usare uno piuttosto che l'altro.