# "Dopo che abbero mangiato": è un refuso?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, orthography

Nel romanzo *La ragazza di Bube* di Carlo Cassola (collana BUR, Rizzoli) ho letto:

> Dopo che **abbero** mangiato, Vilma rigovernò e Mara la aiutò ad asciugare. Tonino mise il bimbo a letto, poi tornò in cucina.

La mia domanda è su questo "abbero". Si tratta di qualche variante di "ebbero" usata in qualche parte d'Italia oppure è un refuso?

Comment: Credo sia un errore, non l'ho mai sentito

Comment: Sicuramente un refuso.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con una breve ricerca su Google Books si trova *abbero* per *ebbero* in Ciullo d'Alcamo e in pochi altri autori antichi (o in dialetti).

Si veda per esempio https://books.google.it/books?id=DYQEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA500&dq=abbero&hl=it&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=abbero&f=false

In un romanzo di Cassola propenderei per il refuso. Non si trova traccia in questa copia: https://books.google.it/books?id=bNHAV9C1socC&pg=PT20&dq=la+ragazza+di+bube&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=abbero&f=false

Confronta con [https://books.google.it/books?id=bNHAV9C1socC&pg=PT20&dq=la+ragazza+di+bube&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Vilma%20rigovernò&f=false](https://books.google.it/books?id=bNHAV9C1socC&pg=PT20&dq=la+ragazza+di+bube&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Vilma%20rigovern%C3%B2&f=false)

Comment: Grazie, @egreg! Immagino che la correzione di "alcuna" per "qualche" che hai fatto sia per la stessa ragione spiegata nei commenti a [questa mia altra domanda](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2325/lespressione-alcuna-differenza-in-una-frase-interrogativa).

Comment: “Alcuna” per “qualche” non è sbagliato, ma antiquato. Spagnolismo (o catalanismo), direi, nel caso specifico. `;-)`

Comment: Catalanismo di Barcellona perché nel catalano delle Baleari dicono "qualque" (pronunciato in modo abbastanza simile all'italiano).

Answer (score -1):

È un errore. Non esiste questo termine.

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE, @Ben! Grazie del tuo post, ma qui ci aspettiamo una risposta un po' più elaborata.

Comment: In realtà *abbero* esiste in letteratura, anche se qui sembra proprio un refuso.